vue-tsc type error using v-select templates and props
Using vue 3.4.31, vuetify 3.6.12, and vue-tsc 2.0.26. I'm trying to use a custom template with a v-select and when I build I get:
TS2339: vuetify v-select Property 'props' does not exist on type '{ item: ListItem<string>; index: number; }'.
My end goal is to show an svg next to each entry in my dropdown. I have a string array and a function that returns the correct path based on the string. My code is pretty much the same as the VPlay example.
<script>
  const myStrings: string[] = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  function getPath(s: string = ''): string {
    return 'm 7 15 l 5 -5 l 5 5 h -10 z';
  }
</script>
<template>
  <v-select :items="myStrings" v-model="selectedString">
    <template v-slot:item="{ props, item }">
      <v-list-item v-bind="props">
        <template #title>
          <svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            class="top-icon select-icon"
          >
            <path
              v-bind:d="getPath(item.raw)"
            />
          </svg>
          {{item.raw}}
        </template>
      </v-list-item>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:selection="{props, item }">
      <svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
        class="top-icon select-icon"
      >
        <path
          v-bind:d="getPath(item.raw)"
        />
      </svg>
      {{item.raw}}
    </template>
  </v-select>
</template>

My scripts are the default from running npm create vue@latest:
"dev": "vite --force",
"build": "run-p type-check \"build-only {@}\" --",
build-only": "vite build",
type-check": "vue-tsc --build --force",

It works great locally with npm run dev, but npm run build gives me the above error.  If I skip vue-tsc and do npm run build-only it builds and runs just fine when deployed. So I'm pretty sure that vue-tsc just isn't getting the correct information about the v-select slots.
Despite the error, which stops CI/CD scripts, the build is fine. If I copy the dist files to the server myself, everything works.
Any ideas what might be causing this and how to fix it?

Argh.  The problem is that the selection slot doesn't take a props parameter. It can take an optional index value though, so it looks like it takes the same two parameters as the item slot, but it doesn't.
Apparently the best way to solve a problem is to ask the internet so you'll see the answer yourself.
